# R: - Why does head() return malformed output for columns with NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been occasionally confused when examining data frames with head() and conditioned on some of the columns. The problem occurs with columns that contain some NAs. E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(1:10, 10), B = c(NA, NA,  runif(98)))
```

These two work as they should:

```
head(df)

head(df[df$A == 1,])
```

But this one returns a curious output:

```
head(df[df$B > 0.5,])

     A         B
NA   NA        NA
NA.1 NA        NA
4     4 0.6452069
5     5 0.5923567
6     6 0.7883836
10   10 0.5252390
```

How can I omit those rows, which numbers become labeled with NAs? Or any other workaround?

Comment: It is not an `head` problem. It is the way you subset `df`.

Comment: `df$B >0.5` returns `NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, ...`. According to `?'['`: _When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a list_. That's why the first two lines of `head` are 'curious'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove those rows from your query:

```
head(df[df$B > 0.5 & !is.na(df$B),])

    A         B
6   6 0.5233364
8   8 0.9972319
9   9 0.8092461
14  4 0.8309064
18  8 0.9985786
20 10 0.8305846
```

Answer (score 1):

As the above answers say, it is about subsetting. Any subsetting with NA results similarly.  Focusing just on df[1:4,]

```
(df$B<0.5)[1:4]
```

results in

```
NA  NA FALSE  TRUE
```

and then

```
df[1:4,][c(NA,NA,FALSE,TRUE),]
```

results in

```
      A        B
NA   NA       NA
NA.1 NA       NA
4     4 0.069598
```

Comment: I don't see what this answer provides more.

Comment: The comment from koekenbakker  was not there when i typed this

Comment: I speak about the other answer.

Comment: Ah. Ok. That got me confused.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that using which() also works:

```
head(df[which(df$B > 0.5),])
```